# Is this sequence bounded and what are the bounds?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence 
$$a_n=\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$
Taking the limit as n goes to infinity is what I did first

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$
$$= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left({(-1)^n}\frac{2^n}{3^n}\right)$$
which would be zero. But I am missing something because the lower bound should be $-\frac{2}{3}$ and the upper bound should be $\frac{4}{9}$.
I know that $a_1= -\frac{2}{3}$ and $a_2=\frac{4}{9}$ but i guess I don't understand the concept of sequences completely.

Comment: Because $2/3 < 1$, the greater $n$ is the smaller $(2/3)^{n}$ is. But there is the minus sign, so when $n$ is even, $(-2/3)^{n}$ is positive and otherwise when $n$ is odd. Thus, it seems to be enough to analyze $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: @Willy.K Ok so what your saying is that any value of $n$ greater than 2 will be less than when $n=1$ and $n=2$, and because they're all less than when $n=1$ or $2$, those are the boundries. So there's no need to take the limit when finding boundries?

Comment: Yes. That's my point!

Comment: You could separate in two subsequences: the one with even $n$ and the other with odd $n$. This is probabibly a nicer way to convince yourself that only $n=1$ and $n=2$ really matter.

Comment: @Willy.K Ok thank you soooo much!

Comment: No problem, man!